# App stuck on multiple place in iOS 14 beta

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios14

I had recently installed the Xcode 12 beta 3 and ran my project on it, but I realized the app stuck on multiple places. I don't know if I am doing something wrong in coding because these are the issues which I did not face in iOS 13 and below.

Here are the list of places where I realized the app get stuck and it just happened only for the first time I ran the app

- First, app got stuck for 20 to 30 seconds at this line in iOS 14 beta

  ```
  [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetooth error:&error]
  ```
- App got stuck while loading URL in `wkwebview`. After 20 seconds, it called its delegate method.

  ```
  func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!){}
  ```
- App got stuck at following line

  ```
  let attributedString = try NSAttributedString(data: data,options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,.characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue],documentAttributes: nil)
  ```

and there are many other places. I don't know if these issues are with the beta version or there are some genuine issues. I never faced these issues in iOS 13 and lower devices.

Comment: If it works without issues on a non-beta iOS version, I wouldn't worry much about it.

Comment: any updates on this issue? are you still facing them?